# Difficulty in designing a business card through CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a business card through HTML and CSS. Following is the design:

[image]

Following is my code:

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 30%;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container {
  padding: 50px 16px;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.info>div:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: right;
  right: 0;
}

.number>div:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: right;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="center">
      <div>Full Name</div>
      <div>Designation</div>
    </div>

    <div class="number">
      <div>R:5435437435</div>
      <div>O:7438573478</div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div>name@example.com</div>
      <div>Address</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From the above code, I am not able to position the Phone Numbers, Email Address and Office Address in proper place where I want. No need of help for background images. I need help only for building the CSS part. Could anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question? You have not formulated it.

Comment: Sir, I want help only in CSS part

Comment: Help to do what? What isn't working as you would expect?

Comment: Hello, please ask specific questions to which answers can be given, like explanation to positioning and centering in CSS. Before that, you could also scout the web for answers! Come back with specific doubts if you don't find what you need. Otherwise, as happens, if you do not know the specific words to search for, try to explain exactly what you don't understand and we will be able to tell you keywords to look for in your search, which is a lot!

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is possible ;)
Give me a plus ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 30%;
}
.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.container {
    padding: 50px 16px;
    position:relative;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.info > div {
    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
/*
.number > div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:70%;
}
*/
.number > .number_container {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="card">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="number">
            <div class="number_container">
                <div>R:5435437435</div>
                <div>O:7438573478</div>
                <div>name@example.com</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <div>Full Name</div>
            <div>Designation</div>
        </div> 
        <div class="info">
            <div>Address</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir, phone numbers are not exactly on the right. Whats the change needed for that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would help? I'm not a professional, correct if I'm wrong with this code.
BR

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 30%;
}
.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.container {
    padding: 50px 16px;
    position:relative;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.info > div {
    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
.number > div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:70%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="card">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="number">
                <div>R:5435437435</div>
                <div>O:7438573478</div>
                <div>name@example.com</div>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <div>Full Name</div>
            <div>Designation</div>
        </div> 
        <div class="info">
            <div>Address</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir, thanks. Its working. But is it possible to position the phone numbers and email section to exact top right in the card? Also, email address is coming out of the card. Anything can be done for that?